# load hierarchy to treeview

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, hierarchy

i v got this class :

```
public class hierarchymain 
   {
       public String label;              // Label to be displayed in treeview
       public int parentId;             // ID of the parent. Root have 0 in parent ID
       public int ID;                     //Id in table. ignore it
   }
```

but i cant figure out the right way to load it into treeview...

```
hierarchy = new List<Hierarchymain> {
            new Hierarchymain{Label="ONE",ParentID=0, ID=0},
            new Hierarchymain{Label="TWO", ParentID=0, ID=1},
            new Hierarchymain{Label="THREE", ParentID=1, ID=2},
            new Hierarchymain{Label="Four", ParentID=2, ID=3},
            new Hierarchymain{Label="five", ParentID=3, ID=4},
            new Hierarchymain{Label="six", ParentID=4, ID=5},
            new Hierarchymain{Label="seven", ParentID=0, ID=6}
        };
```

any ideas?

Comment: You have a loop in items, `new Hierarchymain{Label="ONE",ParentID=0, ID=0}` how can an item have id and parent id =0?

Answer (score 2):

When populating the tree, you can use a dictionary to retrieve the parent of a new item to add. If we can assume that parents are always defined before children, the second `foreach` can be omitted.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, TreeNode>();
var orphans = new Queue<Hierarchymain>();
foreach (Hierarchymain item in hierarchy)
{
    TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(item.Label);
    TreeNode parent;
    if (dict.TryGetValue(item.ParentID, out parent))
        parent.Nodes.Add(newNode);
    else if (item.ParentID == 0)
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(newNode);
    else
        orphans.Enqueue(item);

    dict.Add(item.ID, newNode);
}

// processing nodes, whose parents were created later
foreach (Hierarchymain item in orphans)
{
    TreeNode orphan = dict[item.ID];
    TreeNode parent;
    if (dict.TryGetValue(item.ParentID, out parent))
        parent.Nodes.Add(orphan); // parent found
    else
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(orphan); // the node is a real orphan, adding to the root
}
```

Comment: It almost worked ... but "seven" is added as child of "ONE" , not root... can you fix it?

Comment: @madace since you have a loop in the hierarchy `new Hierarchymain{Label="ONE",ParentID=0, ID=0}` the code may not work for you, if you correct that loop, it works perfect.

Comment: @madace: Of course, since `ParentID` of `seven` is the `ID` of `ONE`. Maybe if the `ID` of `ONE` was `1`, it would work ;)

Comment: the problem is not with ID, the problem is that parent can be lower in the list then child - in this case child is not added to the parent. in multy level hierarchy even sorting by parent does not help :(

Comment: I have edited the answer so it can handle late-defined parents as well.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do that. Before I go, I want to point out that as many commenters mentioned, the provided sample is not correct - if `ParentID=0` represents a root node, then you should not have a node with `ID=0`, so I'll be using the same data as yours but with each item ID incremented. Here is the corrected (and additionally shuffled) data I'll be using for testing:

```
var source = new List<Hierarchymain> {
    new Hierarchymain{ Label="THREE", ParentID=2, ID=3},
    new Hierarchymain{ Label="six", ParentID=5, ID=6},
    new Hierarchymain{ Label="Four", ParentID=3, ID=4},
    new Hierarchymain{ Label="five", ParentID=4, ID=5},
    new Hierarchymain{ Label="TWO", ParentID=1, ID=2},
    new Hierarchymain{ Label="seven", ParentID=0, ID=7},
    new Hierarchymain{ Label="ONE", ParentID=0, ID=1},
};
```

Now the solutions.

(A) Straightforward recursive implementation: Start with the root items, create a node for each item, and then do the same with its children.

```
static void PopulateA(TreeView treeView, IEnumerable<Hierarchymain> source)
{
    AddNodes(treeView.Nodes, 0, source);
}
static void AddNodes(TreeNodeCollection parentNodes, int parentID, IEnumerable<Hierarchymain> source)
{
    foreach (var item in source.Where(item => item.ParentID == parentID))
    {
        var node = parentNodes.Add(item.Label);
        AddNodes(node.Nodes, item.ID, source);
    }
}
```

(B) Different implementation of (A). The problem with (A) is that it has O(N^2) time complexity. But that can easily be improved by preparing a lookup structure at the beginning and still keeping the simplicity.

```
static void PopulateB(TreeView treeView, IEnumerable<Hierarchymain> source)
{
    AddNodes(treeView.Nodes, 0, source.ToLookup(item => item.ParentID));
}
static void AddNodes(TreeNodeCollection parentNodes, int parentID, ILookup<int, Hierarchymain> source)
{
    foreach (var item in source[parentID])
    {
        var node = parentNodes.Add(item.Label);
        AddNodes(node.Nodes, item.ID, source);
    }
}
```

(C) Iterative implementation of the above. If the hierarchy is too deep, the recursive implementations will fail with `StackOverflowException`. That could be solved by turning them into iterative version, sacrificing readability and simplicity. Here is the equivalent of (B):

```
static void PopulateC(TreeView treeView, IEnumerable<Hierarchymain> source)
{
    var itemsByParentId = source.ToLookup(item => item.ParentID);
    var parentNodesStack = new Stack<TreeNodeCollection>();
    var childEnumeratorStack = new Stack<IEnumerator<Hierarchymain>>();
    var parentNodes = treeView.Nodes;
    var childEnumerator = itemsByParentId[0].GetEnumerator();
    try {
        while (true)
        {
            while (childEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                var item = childEnumerator.Current;
                var node = parentNodes.Add(item.Label);
                parentNodesStack.Push(parentNodes);
                childEnumeratorStack.Push(childEnumerator);
                parentNodes = node.Nodes;
                childEnumerator = itemsByParentId[item.ID].GetEnumerator();
            }
            if (childEnumeratorStack.Count == 0) break;
            childEnumerator.Dispose();
            childEnumerator = childEnumeratorStack.Pop();
            parentNodes = parentNodesStack.Pop();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        childEnumerator.Dispose();
        while (childEnumeratorStack.Count != 0) childEnumeratorStack.Pop().Dispose();
    }
}
```

(D) This is the algorithm I usually use. The same idea can be implemented recursively, but I use this for the same reasons mentioned in (C). It works as follows: During the processing, we maintain a map of the created nodes by ID in order to be able to locate the parent nodes. For each item from the input sequence we build a stack containing the items which nodes are not created yet, and then just process it in reverse order. This way we ensure the parents are created before their children.

```
static void PopulateD(TreeView treeView, IEnumerable<Hierarchymain> source)
{
    var itemById = source.ToDictionary(item => item.ID);
    var nodeById = new Dictionary<int, TreeNode>();
    var addStack = new Stack<Hierarchymain>();
    foreach (var nextItem in source)
    {
        // Collect the info about the nodes that need to be created and where
        TreeNodeCollection parentNodes;
        for (var item = nextItem; ; item = itemById[item.ParentID])
        {
            TreeNode node;
            if (nodeById.TryGetValue(item.ID, out node))
            {
                // Already processed
                parentNodes = node.Nodes;
                break;
            }
            addStack.Push(item);
            if (item.ParentID == 0)
            {
                // Root item
                parentNodes = treeView.Nodes;
                break;
            }
        }
        // Create node for each collected item in reverse order
        while (addStack.Count > 0)
        {
            var item = addStack.Pop();
            var node = parentNodes.Add(item.Label);
            nodeById.Add(item.ID, node);
            parentNodes = node.Nodes;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.